Proving that $B_3/\langle (ab)^3\rangle\cong SL_2(\mathbb Z)/\langle -I\rangle$ where $B_3$ is the braid group of three strands
Let $B_2=\langle a,b:aba=bab\rangle$ be the braid group of three strands. It is known that $Z(B_3)=\langle(ab)^3\rangle$. For the sake of simplicity, set $Z=Z(B_3)$. Let $\varphi:B_3/Z\to SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ be the homomorphism define by
$$
\varphi(aZ)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\varphi(bZ)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1\\
-1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My questions (a) What are $\ker \varphi$ and $im \varphi$ ? I noted that
$$
\varphi((ab)^3Z)=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}=-I
$$
but I do not know how it can assist in the proof.
(b) Is there other $2\times 2$ matrices $A,B$ in $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ such that the homomorphism defined by $\varphi(aZ)=A$ and $\varphi(bZ)=B$ will "delivers" the same proof? I guess that $A,B$ must satisfy $ABA=BAB$, but it is not sufficient.

A typo maybe concerning $\varphi(aZ)$ def, twice the same

Thanks @EDX. I fixed it.
